# Create vertical nav bar with both header and form to right as per graphic

Tags: html, css, layout

I want a page to be styled like this: [image]

But I can't get rid of the top left block.

Here is my code:

html:

```
</head>
<body>
  <header>
     <h1>Contacts</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>
      <a href="">Contacts</a>
      <a href="">Call Log</a>
     </nav>

<main>
  <p>Enter text below and click Search button to find a contact</p>
  <form name="searchform">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="">
<br>
<label for="name">Company: </label>
<input id="company" type="text" name="company" value="">
<br>
<label for="ddi">Telephone: </label>
<input id="ddi" type="tel" name="ddi" value="">
<br>

<button name="search" type="button" onclick="process()">Search</button>

</form>

</main>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
/* 
blue header and nav bar, yellow background
 */
body{
    font-size: 125%;
    ackground: #ffff00;
}

nav{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#06425C;
    background-color: #409FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 125px;
    margin-right:15px;
    height:100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav a{
    display:block;
    line-height: 45px;
    height:45px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#486B02;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#486B02;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin:10px 0 10px 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, "Times New Roman";
}

header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #409FFF;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
}

h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
/*   box-sizing:border-box; */
    display: inline;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, "Times New Roman";
}

main{
    display: inline-block;
    width:70%;
    height:100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

input,
textarea {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I have tried for ages but can't seem to work out how to do this.

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "get rid of the top left block" you mean take away the blue space there, you already have that. If you mean you want the blue space, then change the width of your header to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS grid for layout like these.
CSS grid makes it very easy to create layouts like these.
Here is the basic layout for you using CSS grid.

```
body {

  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "h h"
   "c f";
}

nav {
     grid-area: c;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #409fff;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* width: 20%; */
    min-width: 125px;
    /* margin-right: 15px; */
    height: 100vh;

}

nav a {
     display: block;
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    color: #ffffff;
    /* background-color: #486b02; */
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    /* background-color: #486b02; */
    /* padding-left: 50px; */
    margin: 10px 0 10px 5px;
}

header {
  grid-area: h;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    background: #409fff;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*   box-sizing:border-box; */
  display: inline;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial, "Times New Roman";
}

main {
  grid-area:f;
  background-color: yellow;
}

input,
textarea {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```